# Calling prepare with mysqli - SQL syntax error

Tags: mysqli, prepare

```
$q2 = "UPDATE `tasks` SET `title` = ?, task = ?, rules = ?, media = ?, type = ?, xp = ?, available = ?, timestamp = ? WHERE id = ?";
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q2)) {
                $stmt->bind_param("sssssissi", $_POST["tasktitle"], $_POST["editor"], $_POST["rules"], serialize($_POST["media"]), $_POST["type"], $_POST["xp"], $a = 0, strtotime("now"), $_GET['id']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            $r = $mysqli->query($q2) or die($mysqli->error);
```

I got this error msg:

```
﻿You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, task = ?, rules = ?, media = ?, type = ?, xp = ?, available = ?, timestamp = ' at line 1
```

What is problem, and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty certain it's coming from the call to `$mysqli->query()` which needs a properly escaped query (ie, none of that nice safe parameter stuff). That explains why it's complaining at the first `?`.

Quick way to check is to actually comment out the entire `if` statement and se if the error still appears. If so, you know it's the query rather than the prepared statement execution.

My question to you is: why are you executing the prepared statement and *then* trying to run it again as a query?

I think you'll find the `execute` does your update quite well enough. Get rid of the call to `query` and you should be fine.

Comment: It's first time when I use this function. Code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206326/sql-error-when-using-apostrophes
If i comment out if(..){ and } error still appears.

Comment: @TamásK, I don't see the `query` line in the answer you've linked to. That's something you may have left in from a previous version.